# blogchain deploy contract on testnet

Tags: migration, contract, truffle

I am running truffle migrate to deploying a contract and upload it to the testnet.

but the result of deploying it is not understood.

here is the output after running the contract:

```
Using network 'live'.
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
Replacing Voting...
... <some number 1> - what is this number?
Voting: <some number 2> - what is this number? (contract address?)
Saving successful migration to network...
...<some number 3> - what is this number?
Saving artifacts...
```

Answer (score 0):

From the log it seems you're deploying to live network. try to set the network flag when migrating

```
truffle migrate --network  your_network_name_in_config_file
```

You can also set the --verbose-rpc flag to view more information